# p values of latent basis models

Tags: p-value, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, growth-model

I am running a latent basis model and wondering if anyone could provide
insight on how to interpret the p-values of the basis coefficients.
The basis coefficients are set to 0 at T1 and 1 at T9 and others are freely estimated
in this model.
The unstandardized coefficients are as follows.

[image]

My question is, "How do I interpret the p-value for T2 to T6?"

Do they mean,

1. The basis coefficient at Time X is significantly different from the adjoining time point.
   or

2. The basis coefficient at Time X is significantly different from time 1 (which equals
   to 0% growth).

Another question that ties into this is,
If the answer is 1., how do you attain the significance of the slope at that time point?

Thanks everyone for always showing me a way out of my issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p-values are for a test of the null hypothesis that a given coefficient is different from zero, so (2) is correct.

Comment: Thank you for this information. It was helpful!